# set min & max height of lightbox which overrides css when next/prev buttons used

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, lightbox, css

i made a lightbox with comments . the lightbox image container adjusts with width according to the image . the image less then 400 px then the lightbox width is 720 and if image greater then 720px then lightbox width is 960. but now the problem is that . i used 
Jquery code to resize the lightbox image container accoring to the width of the image but suppose 1st image of 400 px then the lightbox size is 720px
and if 2nd image is of greater then 720px then lightbox size is 960px
while moving from 1st image to next/previous image by clicking next /previous button the lightbox takes the width according to the previous image not the current image size width.

my jquery code is

```
  var tpWidth = 720;
  var tpWidthnew = 960; 
  if ( $('.tp-mainimage').width() > tpWidth ) $('#tp-lightboxactitem').width(tpWidthnew);
```

**image size (1024px) greater then 720px then lightbox size is 960px**

[image: image size (1024px) greater then 720px then lightbox size is 960px]

**next image (180px width) less then 720px then also lightbox size is 960px due to previous  image lightbox size being 960px**

[image: next image]

Answer (score 0):

This condition should also be present.

```
if ( $('.tp-mainimage').width() <= tpWidth ) $('#tp-lightboxactitem').width(tpWidth);
```

Also,  if this does not help, you'll need to wait for .tp-mainimage to load(assuming it is being loaded by ajax). So you'll have to make jquery changes there, after the image loads.

Comment: emm yes u can chk it should i host it on some filehosting site ?thanks for helping

Comment: i meant webhosting actually. it would be easier to debug that in chrome wihtout dwnlding.

Comment: soory friend i am just working on localhost rite now . its k , u helped a lot